# Access variadic template structure by its interface

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

There is a hierarchy of classes:

```
template<typename T>
class FeatureInterface1 {
public:
    void f1( void ) { static_cast<T&>(*this)._f1(); }
}

class Feature1 : public FeatureInterface1<Feature1> {
    /* Allow interface class to access private elements */
    friend class FeatureInterface<Feature1>;
private:
    void _f1(void) { /* Do something there */ }
}

template<typename T>
class FeatureInterface2 {
public:
    void f2( void ) { static_cast<T&>(*this)._f2(); }
}

class Feature2 : public FeatureInterface2<Feature2> {
    /* Allow interface class to access private elements */
    friend class FeatureInterface<Feature2>;
private:
    void _f2(void) { /* Do something there */ }
}
```

Then there is a variadic data class:

```
template<typename... FEATURES> class Device {};

template<typename FEATURE, typename... OTHERS>
class Device<FEATURE, OTHERS...> : public Device<OTHERS...> {
public:
    /* Contructor */
    Device(FEATURE feature, OTHERS... others)
        : Device<OTHERS...>(others...),
          m_feature( feature ) {
    }
private:
    FEATURE m_feature;
};
```

and finally the full featured object made at compile time:

```
Device<Feature1, Feature2> device;
```

**The task is to design a `get<>()` function which returns the pointer to particular object using it's interface.** Sample usage:

```
FeatureInterface1<Feature1>* ptr_f = get<FeatureInterface1<Feature1>>(device);
```

In other words something like `get<0>`, `get<1>` ... accessors of `std::tuple` but interface-class-defined rather than index-defined.

My idea is to use `std::enable_if` in connection with `std::is_base_of` ...

The inspiration was taken from https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

I would be very glad to whatever willing to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<FeatureInterface1>` isn't going to work, `FeatureInterface1` isn't a type is a template. Did you really mean `unique_ptr<Feature1>`? But still `get<FeatureInterface1>` (as in, taking a template?)

Comment: @Barry Your are right, a small typo, sorry - I have updated my post to reflect that. Thank you

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<FeatureInterface1<Feature1>> f = get<FeatureInterface1<Feature1>>(device);` cannot be a pointer to the feature in device; unique ptr owns what it points to, and it does not own device.  You probably want to return a `FeatureInterface<Feature1>&`.

Comment: @Yakk Ok, another change, let assume raw pointers.. thank you.

Comment: "In other words something like get<0>, get<1> ... accessors of std::tuple but interface-class-defined rather than index-defined." - but there is also the type-based `std::get()` version for `std::tuple` (if the types are all different); are you sure that `std::tuple` isn't good for your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple actually with `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename FEATURE, typename... OTHERS>
class Device<FEATURE, OTHERS...> : public Device<OTHERS...> {
public:
    ...
    template <typename FEATURE_INTERFACE>
    FEATURE_INTERFACE& get()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<FEATURE_INTERFACE, FEATURE>)
            return m_feature;
        else
            return Device<OTHERS...>::template get<FEATURE_INTERFACE>();
    }
    ...
};
```

Note that you'll get a compilation error if the `Device` doesn't support the requested interface. However, if you want a `nullptr` instead it's not that hard either with an additional specialization for empty `Device`:

```
template<>
class Device<> {
public:
    template <typename FEATURE_INTERFACE>
    FEATURE_INTERFACE* get()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

And then just change the main implementation to return a pointer:

```
template <typename FEATURE_INTERFACE>
FEATURE_INTERFACE* get()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<FEATURE_INTERFACE, FEATURE>)
        return &m_feature;
    else
        return Device<OTHERS...>::template get<FEATURE_INTERFACE>();
}
```

I used a member function instead of non-member because in my opinion the implementation is way simpler this way and I also personally don't like those non-member friend getters :). Also, as Red.Wave mentioned in comments, it's quite easy to make a non-member getter using the member:

```
template <typename FEATURE_INTERFACE, typename... FEATURES>
FEATURE_INTERFACE* get(Device<FEATURES...>& device)
{
    return device.template get<FEATURE_INTERFACE>();
}
```

You might also want to add const-overloads to all these getters for completeness.

Comment: You are missing `friend`, friend: OP doesn't want a member.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont nop. That 'friend' decl - I guess - is just a lubricant for CRTP. Also,  a none member wrapper difinition for the member impl can be as easy as a one-liner template.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename FEATURE, typename... OTHERS>
class Device<FEATURE, OTHERS...> : public Device<OTHERS...> {
public:
  /* Contructor */
  Device(FEATURE feature, OTHERS... others)
    : Device<OTHERS...>(others...),
      m_feature( feature ) {
  }
  template<class T>
  friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, FEATURE>{}, T&>
  get( Device& d ){ return d.m_feature; }
  template<class T>
  friend std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<T, FEATURE>{}, T const&>
  get( Device const& d ){ return d.m_feature; }
```

that should do it.

You may need some `template<class T,class U> decltype(auto) get(U&u, ...){ return get<T>(u); }` to enable ADL (but I don't like the error messages that gives), or a get-template that bounces to a `get_impl` or something.